# Miniature Lepin box door stuck inside box itself

Tags: clone-brands, repair, disassembly

Yes, maybe the title may be confusing, but this image says it all:

[image]

I got a Lepin city set not too long ago, and it included this box. I have no idea how this happened but during use the door mysteriously got stuck inside the box. I'm not really surprised since the set came with an excessively loose head, but I need to get this door out of the box.

Part seperators are too big and bulky to fo the job, so that's not an option. I don't have any minifig crowbars either, and using my fingernails hurts and aren't strong enough. Alternatively I use that golden sword in the picture to grip the handle and attempt to pull out the door but the space available to move the door is very limited, and it gets too tight. Thus when I keep pulling the sword starts to bend, and eventually it loses grip and drops the door. I tried this method countless times and have had no luck.

What can I do? How can I get the door out of the box? (obviously it shouldn't require damaging parts)

Comment: Have you tried a pair of pliers?

Comment: @Aziraphale no, not yet, I doubt I even have those. I'll check later when I have time.

Comment: I'd try wedging a sewing needle or a thin bladed knife into the left side gap between the frame and the door, in order to try to pop the hinge out of the frame.

Comment: Tying a loose loop on a thin enough thread, looping it around the handle, pulling it tight and using the thread to pull the handle outwards could possibly work, even if excessively fiddly.

Comment: So, am I understanding correctly?  It is a LEGO door stuck in a Lepin box?

Comment: @chicks both elements are lepin

Comment: @zovits oh jeez looks like i lack brain for such simple problem, go post that as an answer. I have already solved problem with credit to your comment.

Comment: I could only add an answer detailing the ideas in my proposals, but you could add one based on exactly how you managed to do it, with all caveats and things to be aware of. That'd be worth much more for future visitors :)

Comment: The image for this question is a broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I did it. I wasted two days waiting for answers when the solution is actually very simple.

I just lifted the box cover with my fingertips just *a <sup><sub>tiny</sub></sup> bit*, so that there was enough space to stick something thin between the box cover and the box itself. I did not lift as much as possible because:

- My fingers would slip and drop the box lid again, because the remaining space to lift it all the way out would be too tight
- I need enough space to stick something thin in between.

Then I got a thin-blade knife, as zovits recommended, and pulled it down like a lever, making the other end go up and force the cover out. Easy!

Comment: See, your answer is a lot better than any of the ideas above :)